# I need to split a string on the basis of $, @ , : and ~ but need to leave content inside paranthesis

Tags: angular

So Suppose:  #portgroup data @hello {#Palm ~Beach:main} :and it  was  great.
Need result in ['portgroup data', 'hello', '#Palm ~Beach:main', 'and it  was  great']. Basically wants to skip content inside parenthesis during split.

Comment: Why is this tagged with Angular? I don't see anything Angular specific in this question. Are you asking how to do this in TypeScript?

Comment: @Geo242 Yes in typescript. I have used the expressionstring.splice(/[$@:~](?![^(]*\))/). But Sonar giving denial of service